# Failed to load API definition for swagger URL generated using serverless-auto-swagger plugin

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, serverless, serverless-framework, swagger-2.0

I am using the 'serverless-auto-swagger' plugin to generate a swagger document for my serverless express API written in typescript.

As per instructions,
I installed the the dependency with `npm install -D serverless-auto-swagger`.
Then I added 'serverless-auto-swagger' to the plugins in my serverless file.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-auto-swagger
  - serverless-bundle
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  api:
    handler: "./src/handler.handler"
    events:
      - http:
          path: basket/{basketId}
          method: get
```

After I start my offline server using `serverless offline start`, when I visit the swagger URL, I see the error - Failed to load API definition. Fetch error
Not Found http://localhost:3000/dev/swagger/.json

Comment: Same issue - ever find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the swagger configurations under custom: in serverless.yml file. As a example,

```js
custom:
    autoswagger:
        title: 'string'
        generateSwaggerOnDeploy: true | false
        typefiles: ['./src/types/typefile1.d.ts', './src/subfolder/helper.d.ts']
        apiKeyHeaders: ['Authorization', 'anyOtherName']
        basePath: '/string'
        host: 'http://some-host'
        schemes: ['http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss']
        excludeStages: ['production', 'anyOtherStage']
```

Check the official documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-auto-swagger